# Create multiple tables with multiple inputs using AngularJS 1.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs-1.6

I am working on Angular JS task where i need to take input from a text box and form rows which has two input fields.Consider that rows and columns
Upon entering values in that formed two input fields. A Table with rows and columns should form.
Here is a fiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/iamsaisanthosh/r1zync3g/

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.table = [];
  $scope.cols = [];
  $scope.rows = [];
  $scope.arr = [];
  $scope.arh = [];
  $scope.trr = [];

  $scope.makeArray = function() {
    $scope.trr.length = 0;
    for (var k = 0; k < parseInt($scope.table); k++) {
      $scope.trr.push(k);
    }
    $scope.arr.length = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < parseInt($scope.rows); i++) {
      $scope.arr.push(i);
    }
    $scope.arh.length = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < parseInt($scope.cols); j++) {
      $scope.arh.push(j);

    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input ng-model="table" type="text" ng-change="makeArray()" />
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="o in trr">
        <td> <input ng-model="rows[$index]" type="text" ng-change="makeArray()" />
        </td>
        <td> <input ng-model="cols[$index]" type="text" ng-change="makeArray()" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="o in arr">
          <td ng-repeat="o in arh">Col</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I can take input from a text box and form rows.
Upon entering values in the formed input fields a table with values entered is forming.
Table forms only for the first row inputted values
The problem is i can't do that for more than one row

Not able form Table for second row inputted values
In the above fiddle
Enter 2 in the text field
2 rows will form with two input fields
Enter 3 and 4 respectively in the first row input fields
You can see a table forming with 3 rows and 4 columns
I need the same to happen when i enter values in the second row
A second table should form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   //This piece is wrong right, $scope.rows, $scope.cols are not Strings/Numbers they are arrays and suppose to contain each tabs rows and columns index wise.

   $scope.arr.length = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < parseInt($scope.rows); i++) {
      $scope.arr.push(i);
    }

    $scope.arh.length = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < parseInt($scope.cols); j++) {
      $scope.arh.push(j);

    }
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.table = 0;
   $scope.cols = [];
   $scope.rows = [];

   $scope.makeArray = function() {
      if ($scope.table) {
        return new Array(parseInt($scope.table));
      } else {
        return new Array(0);
      }
   }

   $scope.getRowsCount = function ($index) {
      if ($scope.rows[$index]) {
         return new Array(parseInt($scope.rows[$index]));
      } else {
         return new Array(0);
      }
   }

   $scope.getColsCount = function ($index) {
      if ($scope.cols[$index]) {
        return new Array(parseInt($scope.cols[$index]));
      } else {
        return new Array(0);
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input ng-model="table" type="text" />
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="t in makeArray() track by $index">
        <td> <input ng-model="rows[$index]" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td> <input ng-model="cols[$index]" type="text" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
      <table ng-repeat="t in makeArray() track by $index">
        <tr ng-repeat="r in getRowsCount($index) track by $index">
          <td ng-repeat="c in getColsCount($parent.$index) track by $index">Col</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
It will be great if you can explain me getrowscount and getcols count parent index

Comment: getRowsCout gets an array of null values of length of the no of rows for corresponding  table, so basically u repeat that many times and ignore null values. U repeat for the count not for values in these cases

Comment: Every ng-repeat has its own $index, with $parent u get parent ng-repeat $index, which is what is required in col case, need table index, not row